# Converting a column list from A2:A142 to a list with commas into cell B1; holding a format as "0000" with leading zeros

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

This code works to convert the column list to a concatenated list with commas, however the format doesn't have leading zeros while the VBA loops in B!.

```
Dim i As Integer

Dim s As String

i = 2

Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""

If (s = "") Then

s = Cells(i, 1).Value

    Else
        s = s & ", " & Cells(i, 1).Value

    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
Cells(1, 2).Value = s
```

Answer (score 1):

We will just use formatted values:

```
Sub qwerty()
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As String

i = 2

Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
    If (s = "") Then
        s = Format(Cells(i, 1).Value, "0000")
    Else
        s = s & ", " & Format(Cells(i, 1).Value, "0000")
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

Cells(1, 2).Value = s
End Sub
```

[image]